# Create Criterion for query

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have many rows in table with next format:

```
id  name localSize  city      country

1    Robert  12     NY         USA
2    Bill    12     California USA
3    Artem   12     Kiev       Ukraine
```

Is it possible get only one row from table where localSize is **unique** (first and last)? Using criterion or something from hibernate.

Comment: In this situation, which row do you want to get? Or you want to get row with localSize, which this localSize is unique in this table?

Comment: get only first row

Comment: I added ans answer for getting first or last row. Hope it helps to you for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do method like following for getting first or last row.

```
public List<YourClass> getList() {
    List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<YourClass>();
    Criteria subCriteria = session.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
    subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("localSize"));
    subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.min("id"));
    List<Integer> mins = subCriteria.list();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", mins));
    list = criteria.list();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this materialize the full list in the `else if` block?

Comment: it is'nt possible send localSize as method parameter, it should working by default, I mean If table have 3 rows with localSize = 12, and 5 rows with localSize=20 it should return only two row, one with localSize=12 and one with localSize=20

Comment: Ok,I understood. I will change my answer

Comment: Absolutely I will write))